# calculate coordinates of normal in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, math, rotation

```
var myarray=[
  '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
]
```

I have an array like above that includes a straight line with an specific rotation angle (`45° in this case`) and I'm knowing all points of the line because I have an array that includes all coordinates that are points of the line (`'1'`-characters).

```
var positions=[
  [6,12],
  [7,11],
  [8,10],
  [9,9],
  [10,8],
  [11,7],
  [12,6],
  [13,5],
  [14,4],
  [15,3],
  [16,2],
  [17,1],   
]
```

And I'm also knowing the line rotation angle:

```
var angle=45
```

---

What I'd like to get is drawing at a specific coordinate of the line (`position array`) a `normal` so that my array is looking maybe like this:

(The normal symbolized with **'2's** has a **right angle** to my starting line symbolized with **'1's** and must get a specific length in this case `~16`)

```
var starting_coordinate=[11,7]
var myarray=[
  '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000020000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000002200000010000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000220000100000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000002201000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000212000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000100220000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000001000002200000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000010000000022000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000100000000000200000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
]
```

How is it possible to calculate the positions of the **line of '2's** and draw them into the matrix?

```js
var myarray=[
      '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
]


function draw_tangente(array, angle, length, x, y) {
 var radians=(Math.PI / 180) * angle
 for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
  var new_x = Math.round(Math.cos(radians)*(x-i))
  var new_y = Math.round(Math.sin(radians)*(y-i))
  try {
    var point = array[new_y].split('');point[new_x] = '2';array[new_y] = point.toString().replace(/,/g,'');
  } catch(e) {}
  }
 return array;
}


console.log(draw_tangente(myarray, 45, 10, 11, 7).join('\n'));
```

Comment: That's the opposite of a *tangent* - that second line is a [*normal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Normal_line_to_a_curve).

Comment: Your right I didn't know the englisch word for "Normale" but if the word is just normal, thats super easy. Thanks Oliver

Comment: I see that creepy arrays with "lines"  second time for today,.. is that some course exercise?

Comment: No really not it's my first question today :) No idea why somebody is using something like this "creepy lines" like me!!

Comment: Do you have a generic `draw_line` routine? There is in-fact no need to work with angles or trigonometry. Also, I recommend using the *Bresenham line generation* algorithm - see [here](https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/wiki/Lesson-1:-Bresenham%E2%80%99s-Line-Drawing-Algorithm) for an example implementation in C++.

Comment: Drawing lines in a pixelated space isn't as straightforward as it might first appear. Line thickness and anti-aliasing make the whole topic quite tricky.